# how to remove quotes from a tuple of strings whilst formatting it into another stirng?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format

With the following code:

```
x = "tuple of strings: {}"

y = ("hello", "world")

print(x.format(y))
```

I get the output:

```
tuple of strings: ('hello', 'world')
```

Instead, I would like to get the output:

```
tuple of strings: (hello, world)
```

How to do this? Thanks

Comment: ```hello``` and ```world``` are pre-defined objects right?

Comment: What is the use case..?

Comment: I guess what you are trying to achieve is showing a tuple of strings so for a tuple of strings, there should be `' '`, without that you cannot say that the printed statement is a tuple of string instead of tuple of some objects

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. The `''` means that the value is a string. The names without `''` are variables which means that they had to be predefined and they got their own values.

Answer (score 0):

As provided in other if they are not objects it's not possible to do.

If they are then:

This will output the object (like `hello`):

```py
# str will be like : 'hello' 
globals()[str]
```

or

```py
eval(str)
```

**Note :**

But I recommend to create a dictionary with keys as the strings and values as the corresponding arrays instead of `eval` and `globals()`

like this:

```
dict_ = {'hello': hello, 'world': world}
```

And use this dictionary wherever you want to access the variable

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do? Strings must be enclosed in single `' '` or double quotes `" "`. So I think what you want to do is not possible

Comment: Perhaps he has the same problem in inserting data into tables. You cannot insert values  contains  `('La 'France')` in tuple. I think we might want to replace quote into `('La ''France')`

Answer (score 0):

You can manually remove the ' from the formatted string:

```
x = "tuple of strings: {}"

y = ("hello", "world")

print(x.format(y).replace("'",''))
```

to output:

```
tuple of strings: (hello, world)
```